# How to add effects(like CurlUp, CurlDown etc) to movie created using objective c iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avassetwriter, avmutablecomposition

i have created one movie using AVAssetWriter, AVMutableComposition with images array and audio song and i am saving that to Photo Library...know i want to add effects to that images while creating movie...

is it possible to add effects(like CurlUp, CurlDown etc) to images while creating movie, if so can you please provide me the answer.

```
-(void)writeImageAsMovie:(NSArray *)array toPath:(NSString*)path size:(CGSize)size duration:(int)duration 
 {
CFDataRef imgData;
CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider;
CGImageRef image1;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSString *savedVideoPath1 = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"videoOutput1234videoOutput1234.mp4"];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedVideoPath1])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:savedVideoPath1 error:nil];

NSError *error = nil;

AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:&error];


NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];
AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];


AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];


NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);

writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
[videoWriter addInput:writerInput];


[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];


CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;


int frameCount = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<[array count]; i++)
{
    imgData = (CFDataRef)[array objectAtIndex:i];
    imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData (imgData);
    image1 = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:image1];

    BOOL append_ok = NO;
    int j = 0;
    while (!append_ok && j < 30) 
    {
        if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) 
        {
            printf("appending %d attemp %d\n", frameCount, j);
            CMTime frameTime;


            int64_t value = i;
            int32_t preferredTimeScale = 1;
            frameTime = CMTimeMake(value, preferredTimeScale);


            append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];

        } 
        else 
        {
            printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
        }
        j++;
    }
    if (!append_ok) {
        printf("error appending image %d times %d\n", frameCount, j);
    }
    frameCount++;
    CVBufferRelease(buffer);
}

if (AVAssetWriterStatusCompleted) {
    [writerInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWriting];
}

}
```

Comment: Hey i also have the same problem!!!

Comment: I am also searching for same :( . you got the solution ?

Comment: I am also searching for the same ..If anyone find that please help..